# How can I build a bipolar (+Vgs,on/ -Vgs,off) driver with BJTs for MOSFETs?

Tags: bjt, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, push-pull, power-supply

I am beginner in driver circuitry. I am trying to do a MOSFET driver that can work at over 300kHz with a current sink capability of 10A.

I also want it to give a bipolar output like -10/30V.

I found this totem pole circuit with the BC545C PNP  and BC557C NPN  BJTs (100mA,45V.) In simulation, it it gives me the waveform of -10/30V. I looked at the datasheet of the component and saw that their current sourcing capability is very low.

[image]

I tried to use the TIP35C (NPN even with LTspice 2SCR582D3) and TIP36C (PNP same for this model 2SAR582D3) high current sourcing (25A-60V) but I can't get the waveform correct.

What should I add or correct in my circuit?

[image]

Comment: How is the MOSFET hooked up? Also, what MOSFET are you trying to drive? 30Vgs is high.

Comment: That's quite extreme. No MOSFETs I'm aware of require +30V, and fewer and fewer require such currents these days -- certainly not at such frequencies. What is your application? Do you know you actually need that much drive power?

Comment: You are not using MOSFET's. You are using bipolar transistors. First of all, use MOSFET's if you want to make a driver for them or modify the title of your question (or explain what you want to do exactly). ;)

Comment: 1, The GND is placed incorrectly. 2. MOSFET doesn't need negative voltage, SiC MOSFET maybe. 3, Voltages are way too high. 4. Practical implementation would need isolated +/- PSU in order to keep the drain at GND potential.

Comment: @MOSFET 
Thanks for your answer, It's just one mosfets I want to stress (so stress its gate) not to switch for power.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Thanks, 
 Yeah it's for SiC MOSFETs, that's why I put negative. For simulation can I implement Isolated PSU?

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, for your answer, I just want to stress one device, under high voltage to see the effect of it in the gate.  Their are some drivers that exist but their maximum rating voltage is lower max 30V swinging (Vgs,on/ Vgs,off). I want to go higher.

Comment: @Fredled thanks for your answer, I am using BJts to do driver for MOSFETs that's why I wrote my title like that. It can be confusing perhaps

Comment: You are forcing 260mA to Q2 base but only 40mA flows through its collector. You are oversaturating it. You are temporary latching this transistor. Ib/Ic should be about 1/10. If you worry about speed use high-speed bjt.

Comment: Thanks for replying to the comments. We understand better now what you want to do. You want to stress test a Sic Mosfet.  If you apply voltage on the mosfet gate (Vgs) above max rating (30V instead of 20V) it will be destroyed immediately.

Comment: Not immediately actually, but leakage increases, threshold shifts, and the likelihood of failure increases, probably more or less exponentially as voltage goes up. For reference, I've heard of anywhere from 30 to 70V blowing an Si gate; SiC seem to be thinner and I would expect 25-50V actual breakdown. In other words, you're creating a transistorcide machine here. Far less than 10A is required to do this.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Thanks for your answer, I tried to use BJTs with frequency, I am simulating first to see what is the result. But I think I am missing something. I am considering the transition frequency fT in the datasheet it is high like 100MHz and I am wondering if this transition frequency is for switching capability of the bjts.

Because my circuit works well at lowe frequency (below 200kHz) but when I increase the value waveforms become weird.

Comment: I don’t see any load. Place a 1n capacitor to output or gate of mosfet.

Comment: hello @MichalPodmanický I've put a mosfet at the end. 
I want to add image in my comment but I don't know how to do it. I saw that I can add with ctrl+G but it doesn't work